# Is support to something correct?

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence I think **to** should be omitted.

> As tensions between the U.S. and China rise over the novel coronavirus pandemic, India, which is set to take over as the next Chairperson of the World Health Organisation’s decision-making executive body in May, is faced with a major choice on whether to support a U.S. move to reinstate Taiwan’s observer status at the World Health Assembly (WHA) or **to** China’s opposition to it.

Because the sentence can be re-written as

> is faced with a major choice on whether to support **to** China’s opposition to it.

and here **to** is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase is wrong as written, but there's more than one way to fix it.

You can remove **to**:

> … whether **to support** <sup>a U.S. move to reinstate Taiwan’s observer status at the World Health Assembly (WHA)</sup> or <sup>China’s opposition to it</sup>.

You can add **support**:

> … whether **to support** <sup>a U.S. move to reinstate Taiwan’s observer status at the World Health Assembly (WHA)</sup> or **to support** <sup>China’s opposition to it</sup>.

---

While those are the correct ways of writing the two variations of the sentence, adding **support** actually makes it easier to understand what's going on.

In the first version, reading comprehension fails as soon as you get to this:

> … at the World Health Assembly or China's opposition to it.

That phrase on its own makes no sense. It reads as if it's saying this:

> … at <sup>the World Health Assembly</sup> or  <sup>China's opposition to it.</sup>

Or, to shorten it further:

> … [at] China's opposition to it.

However, the **or** is not connected with the **at** in that phrase, but back to  **whether to support** in the previous part of the sentence, which is already out of mind. To understand it, you have to get to the end of the sentence, realize it doesn't make any sense, then back up and read the previous part of the sentence again.

By making it read **to support**, it makes you remember that **to support** was already used earlier in the sentence, and lets you use the conjunction properly.

It actually took me several minutes (literally), of reading and rereading the sentence (or at least the last part of it) to understand exactly what was being said. Once I added **support**, everything became easier for me. Even *understanding* what's going on, if I just remove the **to**, I have difficulty reading the sentence smoothly without using the kind of superscript technique I did in this answer.

---

Finally, compare the two unannotated versions of the relevant portion of the sentence to see which reads better.

But also note that the relevant portion is only *a third* of the total sentence itself. The extreme length of the sentence makes any kind of parsing in the latter third that much harder. In short, it's a very poorly written sentence, and it really needs to be broken up and rephrased anyway.

> … whether to support a U.S. move to reinstate Taiwan’s observer status at the World Health Assembly (WHA) or China’s opposition to it.
>
> … whether to support a U.S. move to reinstate Taiwan’s observer status at the World Health Assembly (WHA) or to support China’s opposition to it.